# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I tried this code

```
  let secondView = SecondViewController(nibName: "secondView", bundle: nil)
    secondView.secondViewLabel.text = self.TextBox.text
    navigationController?.pushViewController(secondView, animated: true)
```

I am trying to pass the value from the text box to a label in the next view controller.But i get an error

I also tried copying the text box value to a sting declared in the second View controller that also returns nil.

```
let secondView = SecondViewController(nibName: "secondView", bundle: nil)
    secondView.toPass = self.TextBox.text
    navigationController?.pushViewController(secondView, animated: true)
    println(secondView.toPass) // i get the string printed here
```

in second view controller

```
      var toPass:String!
```

in view did load

```
    secondLabel.text = toPass
     println(toPass) // i get the string printed nil
```

help me guys i am new to swift

Comment: What is TextBox? What type is it? What is the type of TextBox.text?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var TextBox: UITextField!

Answer (score 0):

Make the type of toPass a String conditional like so

`var toPass: String?`

In viewDidLoad, do this :

```
if let passedString = toPass {
    secondLabel.text = toPass
    println(toPass)
}
```

Then put a breakpoint inside the if let block to see if toPass ever had a value or it isn't being set at all. Really need to know what type the TextBox is.

[Edit 2]

If the problem is that the value is being set before the viewController `secondView` has been decoded from a nib, I'd suggest you make a convenience initializer that uses the initWithNib but also takes the extra title string or whatever it is. There you can set the value of your textLabel's text to the parameter the new initializer takes. Of course this would mean that you'll have to subclass UIViewController.

Comment: It is not entering into the loop.I already mentioned the value of toPass is null

Comment: why cant i pass the the string directly as mentioned first in my question.Any idea ??

Comment: IMO `secondView.secondViewLabel.text = self.TextBox.text` is being called before the nib has been decoded and therefore it is not being set because there is not binding for `secondViewLabel` yet.